# How do I tell if my mail system has been compromised?

Tags: security, email

My webmaster catch-all email address started receiving a lot of "Delivery Status Notification (Failure)" replies from various email systems. In the order of 1 per hour.

It's obviously Spam being sent, as the content is about medications. I'm trying to figure out if

1)It is not being sent by us but the reply-to field is being set to our site, and therefore we receive the failure notification or
2) Our system has been compromised and it's being sent by us, hurting our reputation. Also - if this is the case, where do I look to fix the problem?!

Thanks!

Here is an example:

```
 Delivery to the following recipient failed permanently:

 grdchurch@mail.calvinseminary.edu

 Technical details of permanent failure:
 Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the recipient domain. We         recommend contacting the other email provider for further information about the cause of    this error. The error that the other server returned was: 550 550 5.1.1   <grdchurch@calvinseminary.edu>... User unknown (state 13).

 ----- Original message -----

 Received: by 10.204.152.70 with SMTP id f6mr6872450bkw.7.1341224023720;
 Mon, 02 Jul 2012 03:13:43 -0700 (PDT)
 Received: by 10.204.152.70 with SMTP id f6mr6872447bkw.7.1341224023673;
 Mon, 02 Jul 2012 03:13:43 -0700 (PDT)
 Return-Path: <Ester7CB4674@mysite.com>
 Received: from 94.98.142.218 ([94.98.142.218])
 by mx.google.com with ESMTP id hi9si10538192bkc.151.2012.07.02.03.13.38;
 Mon, 02 Jul 2012 03:13:39 -0700 (PDT)
 Received-SPF: neutral (google.com: 94.98.142.218 is neither permitted nor denied by   best guess record for domain of Ester7CB4674@mysite.com) client-ip=94.98.142.218;
 Authentication-Results: mx.google.com; spf=neutral (google.com: 94.98.142.218 is neither permitted nor denied by best guess record for domain of Ester7CB4674@mysite.com)    smtp.mail=Ester7CB4674@mysite.com
 Date: Mon, 02 Jul 2012 03:13:39 -0700 (PDT)
 Message-Id: <20120702131340.6C18454BE719A3A513E9@USER-PC>
 From: Leslie Browning <Ester7CB4674@mysite.com>
 To: grdchurch <grdchurch@calvinseminary.edu>
 Reply-To: Maryanne Whitehead <Terry1DA24@starlane411.com>
 Subject: For grdchurch
 Mime-Version: 1.0
 Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

 best ED meds! Be confident! Buy here http://www.akermedic.ru/

 B3B0ED3F2E14A898C2C644020D7E9A8071
 30DA492A4CF3EB0A0E3DE1371040BE5C81
 4C9CF9C9AC2D7881DACD5D1B0A9A460
```

Comment: Also, my guess would be that the `From:` field in the spam mail was spoofed, rather than that your email server is compromised.

Answer (score 1):

Try installing some anti-virus and anti-malware like:

http://www.malwarebytes.org/

http://www.microsoft.com/security/pc-security/mse.aspx

and run a full system scan, see what you come up with.

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the mail header a

```
Received: from 94.98.142.218 ([94.98.142.218])
```

If the IP there is unequal to the ip of any of your hosts, its just the spoofed `From` header. The `Received` header are not created by the sender but by the intermediate mailserver which (probably) also sent you the `Delivery Status Notification (Failure)` message. This cannot be spoofed trivially. An attacker would also not need to spoof that as he already *had* your system as a spoof.

So I think this points in the direction of a spoofed `From` header which points back to you. No warranties of course.